# When $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n+1}}{(1+ \frac{r^2}{n(n-2)})^{n/2}} dr$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $n\geq 3.$
Put $I_{n}= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n+1}}{(1+ \frac{r^2}{n(n-2)})^{n/2}} dr$ and $J_{n}= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+ \frac{r^2}{n(n-2)})^{n-2}} dr$

> My Question is: For which $n$, $I_n$ is finite? Is $J_n$ is finite for  the same $n$ (as in $I_n$)? How should I justify? Can we expect to compute explicitly?

Edit: When $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n+1}}{(1+ \frac{r^2}{n(n-2)})^{n}} dr$ is finite?

Comment: $I_n$ diverges for all $n$.  $J_n$ converges for $n>4$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use equivalences to see that $\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n/2}\sim C_n r^n$ for $r\to \infty$, where $C_n=\left(\frac{1}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n/2}$.

Then, $\frac{r^{n+1}}{\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n/2}}\sim C_n^{-1}\,r$ as $r\to \infty$ and $I_n$ diverges for all $n$.

---

Similarly, we have $\frac{r^{n-1}}{\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n-2}}\sim \left(n(n-2)\right)^{n-2}\frac{1}{r^{n-3}}$.

Therefore, $J_n$ converges for $n>4$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: Dr. MV, Thanks: What if I take $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{r^{n+1}}{(1+ \frac{r^2}{n(n-2)})^{n}} $?

Comment: @abcd You're welcome! My pleasure.  -Mark

Comment: For this last one, just follow the same way forward as in the previous two.

Comment: Would you please explain me following step bit more:
$\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n/2}\sim C_n r^n$ for $r\to \infty$?

Comment: What is a meaning of this and how should I make it precise?

Comment: Note that as $r\to \infty$ the ratio $\frac{C_nr^n}{\left(1+\frac{r^2}{n(n-2)}\right)^{n/2}}\to 1$.